# unique "key" / table should have a unique `key` prop, or set `rowKey

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key

Question: How to pass / create and pass unique key to Radio Button , also i have a Table component that takes data(arra) and it also says that `[antd: Table]` Each record in dataSource of table should have a unique `key` prop, or set `rowKey` . Thank you in advance.

```
    const userRoles = [
    {
        key: "ROLE_ADMIN",
        name: "Admin"
    },
    {
        key: "ROLE_USER",
        name: "User",
    }
];


class RoleUpdate extends PureComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userRole: props.role,
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            userRole: {
                role: event.target.value
            }
        });
        this.props.onRoleChange(event.target.value);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Radio.Group value={this.state.userRole.role} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                {userRoles.map(role => {
                    return <Radio.Button value={role.key}>{role.name}</Radio.Button>
                })}
            </Radio.Group>

        )
    };

}

export default RoleUpdate;

<Table size={"middle"}
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={this.state.results}
                   />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create unique keys for React elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549424/how-to-create-unique-keys-for-react-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass a key attribute to elements returned from within the loop or map. Assuming userRoles has key property which is unique it can be used as a key like `key={role.key}` on `Radio.Button`

```
render() {
    return (
        <Radio.Group value={this.state.userRole.role} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            {userRoles.map(role => {
                return <Radio.Button key={role.key} value={role.key}>{role.name}</Radio.Button>
            })}
        </Radio.Group>

    )
};
```

and for the table you need to specify which key from within the data needs to be taken as a key by specifying the `rowKey` attribute

```
<Table size={"middle"}
  columns={columns}
   rowKey={"id"} // specify any key which has unique value within this.state.resukts
  dataSource={this.state.results}
/>
```

Comment: so  i need to somehow iterate through the array of data and take for example email as the unique key and assign to key prop ? rowKey={this.state.results.map()}...

Comment: If you are taking about adding unique key to Table then no, you just need to speicfy which attribute in your data holds unique values. For instance say the data is `userRoles`, you will pass the `rowKey="key"` as key attribute in userRoles holds unique key

Comment: However when mapping over data and rendering items, you need to pass a `key` prop to the element returned from map, and that key attribute can be any unique value specified like `key={item.key}` or even be `key={index}` in worst case scenario

Comment: Currently i have weird behavior and i have a feeling is because of current console error messages -> I have a live search where data changes and each person have radio for example two radio buttons, currently if i locate somebody on second row and change state of the button , when i search again and and the person who appeared on the second row seems to have same option highlighted  even tho its a different person, sorry for crap explanation

Comment: You may be storing state based on index. Hard to say though unless you show the relevant code

Comment: thank you for your time, i have posted a question before but no answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62101695/live-search-bug?noredirect=1#comment109835472_62101695

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `key` attribute to each element of `.map()`.

The way usually I do is using `(role, index)` option what you can add as:

```
<Radio.Group value={this.state.userRole.role} onChange={this.handleChange}>
  {userRoles.map((role, index) => {
     return <Radio.Button key={index} value={role.key}>{role.name}</Radio.Button>
  })}
</Radio.Group>
```